# CSS Percentage Issues

Tags: html, css, percentage

I have a footer image that displays within a footer div. The footer image is mostly black, so I want a div to the right and left area of the footer to be black and extend to the edge of the page. I'm unable to accomplish this. I would appreciate any help. Below is my css code and then the associated HTML code:
CSS:

```
body{
width: 1196px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.footer {
    width:1196px;
    float: left;
    height: 572px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="footer"><img src="images/footer.jpg" width="1196" height="572"/></div>
```

Comment: what "percentage issue" are you referring to in your header and tags? You have no percentage values in your CSS, and also your question doesn't contain anything about percentages?

Comment: I knew the answer would be percentage related.

Comment: but what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is removing the fixed `width` from `body` and giving `width:100%` to `footer` then you can center the `footer img` using `display:block` + `margin:auto`

```css
body {
  margin: 2px auto 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.footer {
  max-width: 100%;
  background: black
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/1196x572" />
</div>
```

Comment: it works, I had to re-align the rest of the page, but once that was done it looked pretty good.  THNX